# Using mixed type of >> and getline

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

My task is to enter a string input into a char array. Here's what it's like :

```
char name[30];
cin>>name;
cin.getline(name,29);
cout<<name;
```

as with the input is : `Ly Nguyen Khang`
and the result only return `Nguyen Khang`
Please anybody help me understand what is wrong with this :(

part of my code :

```
#define INPUT_HELP_NAME "Please input name: "
#define INPUT_HELP_PHONE "Phone: "
    cout << INPUT_HELP_NAME;
        cin.getline(res->name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH-1);
        cout << INPUT_HELP_PHONE;
        cin >> res->phone;
```

when it runs , it shows something like this :

```
Please input name : Phone :
```

Comment: you write `Ly` to `name` with `cin>>name;`, then you overwrite it with the rest of the name with `cin.getline(name,29);`

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: In general, mixing line-based and field-based input doesn't work well together. Use just line-based for interactive programs where you regularly prompt the user for a value. Then, use stringstreams (or lexical_cast) to convert the whole line into the according value and check for errors. Good luck!

Comment: actually my teacher requires us to use char as a test of our knowledge  and also there are several cin later such as phone number , birthday ... .These are also set to char type , which i can easily use cin>> to read them , however the problem with the function cin>> is that its stop whether it hits the space between them so its impossible to use cin>> for name .

Comment: The problem with char arrays is that `operator>>` will happily write beyond the end of the array, causing a so-called buffer overrun. This is the source of many exploits in software and there is no excuse to teach such careless programming. Using a `std::string` will automatically resize the string.

Comment: sir it is actually a homework which purpose is to test our knowledge , however i have found the solution in these above post  . Thank you for looking at my post kind sir , have a goodday ^^.

Comment: it is to use cin.ignore() before cin.getline

Answer (score 1):

You `cin`ed it twice, causing it to not work. This is the correct way to do it:

```
char name[30];
cin.getline(name,29);
cout<<name;
```

The `cin.getline(name,29);` is already `cin`ed it, so there is no need for `cin>>name;`ing it, that makes your results change because your code said to `cin` it twice.

Comment: ah yeah that was actually what i did earlier on , but the compiler skip the input and goes straight to cout , as i read some similar post about this they say that because if you put the getline then follow by operator >> or << cause them to skip the getline , so the fix is to put those operators before getline , but of course there are new problems to fix like this one so...

Comment: @Khang: whatever you've read is either wrong or you misunderstood it.  Bob's code works, assuming `cin` is not in an error state beforehand and doesn't fail to read through to the newline or EOF.  You should start checking that every input operation works - else `cerr << "failure!\n"` - so a bad stream state doesn't make correct code appear broken.

Comment: the compiler actually skip it , not just my assumption . i will put a part of my code on the thread above.